# Change propagation in N-Tier Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

Does N-Tier Entity Framework (http://ntieref.codeplex.com/) support change propagation to clients?
I mean if there are 3 WPF clients and one of them adds a product, is it possible that the 2 other clients see this product is added?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there is no such functionality out-of-the box.

You would have to implement this 'custom logic' on your own, e.g. by implementing a WCF duplex service, allowing clients to register for updates on the server. On each update, the server could call back to the registered clients for notification.